# dijit style claro not in Google CDN

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

dojo's Theme Tester is Showing theme claro as one available theme in http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/dojo-2010-04-12/dojotoolkit/dijit/themes/themeTester.html?theme=claro
But claro is not accessible from Google CDN.
I've also tried to use claro from the same place where the ThemeTester is pulling. But layout doesn't look the same. rather it looks broken. However my same code works with other themes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claro will be officially released with Dojo 1.5 (in RC now). Until it is released it it is not going to be available from CDNs — only official releases are pushed to CDN. Just wait a bit, and you will be able to use it from CDN.

Theme Tester pulls Claro from the test server using a build optimized for debugging and therefore slow. Please do not use it for any of your code. Use a local copy instead.